# How to duplicate a partitioned table

Tags: oracle, duplicates

I am constructing a test environment. Oracle 11g is my database. My goal is to place 80 million records in this database. I will start with 1 million records, which will be loaded into the partitioned table. Is there a way to duplicate the initial partition to create 80 partitions for a grand total of 80Meg records. The constraint is this process should take no longer than two hours to generate 80 million records.

Answer (score 0):

After inserting the first partition, follow this principle:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (partition_column, col1, col2, col3, ...)
SELECT level, col1, col2, col3, ...
FROM my_table
CONNECT BY level < 80
```

The `partition_column` is just an assumption about your actual partitioning. You might have to change some values in the `SELECT` list for the new records to be put into different partitions. It helps to turn off constraints and indexes during this insert.